# document.querySelector .value return value

Tags: javascript

I have a web page with a few radio button selections. Not all of the radio button options have to be selected. To get the value of each of the Radio Button options I am using this:

```
var hotend = document.querySelector('input[name="hotend"]:checked').value;
```

I would think that this should set hotend to null? But it seems like this crashes the webpage when there hasn't been a radio button selected in the group because the rest of function does not run. How do I capture this and process the rest of the function?

Here is the entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
<title>test</title>

</head>
 
<body>
    <h1>parts</h1>
    <label for="printer">Choose a part:</label>
    <select id="printer" name="printer">
        <option value="none">Select Printer</option>
        <option value="CR_10">CR-10</option>
        
        
    </select>
    <br />   
    Choose a hotend:
    <div class="flex-container">   
        <div>            
            <input type="radio" id="creality_OEM" name="hotend" value="Creality_OEM">
            <label for="creality_OEM">Creality OEM</label>
        </div>
        <div>            
            <input type="radio" id="micro_swiss" name="hotend" value="Micro_Swiss">
            <label for="micro_swiss">Micro Swiss</label>
        </div>
        
    </div>
   
<button class="button" onclick="createParts();" >Generate Parts List</button> 
<div id="parts_list">
test    
</div>
<div id="test">
 something  
</div>
<script>

function createParts(){
    var partsList="";
    var errorList="";
       
    const printer = document.getElementById('printer').value;
    let nullTest = document.querySelector('input[name="hotend"]:checked');
    const hotend= nullTest.value ?? "";
        
    document.getElementById('parts_list').innerHTML=partsList;
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="something";
    
}

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. We need the HTML as well.

Comment: Here is what you requested

Answer (score 0):

Your code "crashes" because you're trying to access the property `value` on a `null`˙object.

Because `document.querySelector('input[name="hotend"]:checked')` returns `null` when there's no radio buttons selected.

You're basically doing this when no radio button is selected: `null.value`.

Try this:

```js
const hotendElement = document.querySelector('input[name="hotend"]:checked');
const hotend = hotendElement.value ?? "No hotend selected";
```

Also, do not use `var`. Use `const` and `let`.

Comment: I changed the function to this and it still "crashes"
function createParts(){
    var partsList="";
    var errorList="";
       
    const printer = document.getElementById('printer').value;
    let nullTest = document.querySelector('input[name="hotend"]:checked');
    const hotend= nullTest.value ?? "";
        
    document.getElementById('parts_list').innerHTML=partsList;
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="something";
    
}
What am I missing?

Comment: @Rick check if any other `document.getElementById` are returning null.

Comment: I actually found a fix, so doing a hotendElement.value on a nell element will throw an error. the coalescing ?? only works on null or undefined elements. You have to optional chain it first to escape the error before you coalesce it. So something like this
hotend = document.querySelector('input[name="hotend"]:checked')?.value ?? "";